# Change language in mobile application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, compact-framework, localization, windows-mobile-5.0

I make application for windows mobile 5 in Visual Studio 2005 in C#. How can change language of my mobile application. I made each form localizable and i have 2 resources files for each form. but i dont know how to change the language. It doesnt have to be changable in program beacuse i need to 2 version of this application

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to the Desktop Framework, you can't change `CurrentThread.UICulture` programmatically. The .NET Compact Framework will only follow the user's preference.